# MouseAppearance and cursor problems

Tags: front-end

I have to create a `Graph` object, which can be manipulated by the user, though I do not want to have the `Graph`-specific cursor (an arrow with an `UndirectedEdge` symbol next to it) not to confuse the user with any extra information. I assumed this would work:

```
MouseAppearance[
 Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3,3 <-> 1},
  ImageSize -> 200,
  EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Black, AbsoluteThickness@2, Arrowheads@.1, 
      MouseAppearance[Arrow[#1, .1], "Arrow"]} &),
  VertexShapeFunction :> ({Hue[.6, .2, .8], 
      MouseAppearance[Disk[#1, .1], "Arrow"]} &)
  ],
 "Arrow"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But it doesn't work. While all graphics objects and the whole graph itself are wrapped into `MouseAppearance` still the `Graph`-specific cursor appears when I move the mouse away of edges or nodes. Over nodes and edges, the standard arrow cursor is displayed correctly, as expected. Unfortunately, when I capture the screen with the cursor included, it **always** saves the normal arrow cursor irregardless how it looks on screen. Strange. That's why I did not include a picture with a cursor over it.

Can anyone answer the following questions?

1. Why `MouseAppearance[..., "Arrow"]` does not work here (only partially)?
2. How can the `Graph`-specific cursor appearance be invoked? The documentation for [`MouseAppearance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MouseAppearance.html) (under More nformation) does not list it among the built-in ones.
3. Why <kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> or any other screenshot application is unable to capture the `Graph`-specific cursor?

Platform is: Win7 64bit

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Heike's answer has a strong virtue of simplicity, but it has two downsides. It strips the `Graph`-specific context menus, and it causes the output to not evaluate as a `Graph` if copied back to input. Here's a version which preserves those properties:

```
StripGraphMouseAppearance[x_Graph] := 
 RawBoxes[ToBoxes[x, StandardForm] /. 
   TagBox[contents_, MouseAppearanceTag["NetworkGraphics"]] :> 
    contents]
```

Now, simply apply `StripGraphMouseAppearance` whenever you want to strip the appearance in output.  E.g., the example in the question would be reformulated as:

```
StripGraphMouseAppearance[
 Graph[{1 <-> 2, 2 <-> 3, 3 <-> 1}, ImageSize -> 200, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Black, AbsoluteThickness@2, Arrowheads@.1, 
      Arrow[#1, .1]} &), 
  VertexShapeFunction :> ({Hue[.6, .2, .8], Disk[#1, .1]} &)]]
```

Basically, `Graph` typesets with the `MouseAppearance` built into it. My code looks for the box form of `MouseAppearance` and strips it out. One could conceivably rewrite MakeBoxes rules for `Graph` directly to do this, but doing so correctly would be a much more difficult exercise, as it would require reverse-engineering the rules we have now and carefully overriding them...and such a solution might not be stable across different Mathematica versions.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know the answers to questions 1 and 3, but to get the cursor appearing as an arrow everywhere in the `Graph` you could wrap your graph in `Show`, e.g.

```
Show@Graph[{1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 1}, ImageSize -> 200, 
  EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Black, AbsoluteThickness@2, Arrowheads@.1, 
      Arrow[#1, .1]} &), 
  VertexShapeFunction :> ({Hue[.6, .2, .8], Disk[#1, .1]} &)]
```

Comment: Interesting workaround! Since the right-click menu for graph-editing is gone, I assume that `Show` effectively converts `Graph` objects to `Graphics` objects.

Comment: +1 Heike, you beat me to it! @István: Yes, you can check by hitting it with `InputForm` and comparing to the `Graph` without the `Show`. As for the screenshot thing, I get the same behaviour as you using the default gnome screenshot tool (in Ubuntu 11.10).

Comment: Yes, the problem is that `MouseAppearance` is used when typesetting `Graph` objects. Your `MouseAppearance` doesn't work because, if you look at the underlying representation in the front end, the typeset stage effectively wraps `MouseAppearance` around all of the individual elements of the `Graph`. If you would find the answer interesting, I could propose a separate answer which preserves the contextual menu while stripping the inner `MouseAppearance`, although the `Show` method prescribed here is certainly simpler and may be good enough for you.

Comment: Yes, @JohnFultz, please propose that separate answer!