# To style Sound object

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, customization, sound

While doing some signal processing research my aesthetic feelings were heavily struck by following output:
[image: Sound object with very long caption not displayed in full size]
The problem here is that `211.96 s` label is partially covered by buttons.
I can manually resize the object output in an individual case, but I also want to be able to make it programmatically, but unfortunately I could not find any `ImageSize` or similar options in the `Sound` documentation and nothing like `Style[sound, Larger]` works. So the question is:

**How to programatically resize the output of a `Sound` object?**

The most naive approach I've tried is to use
[image: Usage of Magnify on a Sound object output]
but it magnifies the font size as well. I'm fine with it for now, but in case anyone knows better solution I appreciate your answers a lot! Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be available with `Options` so let's edit this manually. So you can inspect the output or use `ToBoxes` to know what needs to be changed. And change it:

```
sound = Sound[{SoundNote["C"], SoundNote["G"]}]

ToBoxes[
   sound
] /. GraphicsBox[gr_, opts___, ImageSize -> _, opts2___
  ] :> GraphicsBox[gr, opts, opts2, ImageSize -> 500
] // RawBoxes
```

[image]

Learned from [John Fultz's answer: MouseAppearance and cursor problems](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2172/5478)

Comment: Wow, that's an impressive low level code :) Thank you! I have no idea what this all box stuff is.

Comment: And thank you for learning link!